# CSS Selector Works in Browser Console But Not in Python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use login to an [Investors Business Daily](https://myibd.investors.com/secure/signin.aspx?eurl=https://marketsmith.investors.com/) service using python for selenium using a CSS selector.  I found a unique atribute under an input tag which runs successfullyl in the chrome browser console:

```
$$("[data-gigya-placeholder='Email']")
```

However, the coresponding python does not work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://myibd.investors.com/secure/signin.aspx?eurl=https://marketsmith.investors.com/")

login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-gigya-placeholder='Email']")
```

Full error log:

> NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_26004/2365346870.py in 
> 1 # find the element for entering the username
> 2 #login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[data-gigya-placeholder='Email']")
> ----> 3 login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-gigya-placeholder='Email']")
> 4
> 5
>
> ~\miniconda3\envs\selenium_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
> in find_element_by_css_selector(self, css_selector)
> 596             element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')
> 597         """
> --> 598         return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
> 599
> 600     def find_elements_by_css_selector(self, css_selector):
>
> ~\miniconda3\envs\selenium_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
> in find_element(self, by, value)
> 974                 by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
> 975                 value = '[name="%s"]' % value
> --> 976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
> 977             'using': by,
> 978             'value': value})['value']
>
> ~\miniconda3\envs\selenium_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
> in execute(self, driver_command, params)
> 319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
> 320         if response:
> --> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> 322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
> 323                 response.get('value', None))
>
> ~\miniconda3\envs\selenium_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py
> in check_response(self, response)
> 240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
> 241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
> --> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> 243
> 244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):
>
> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"[data-gigya-placeholder='Email']"}

I've tried an alternative python syntax which results in a similar error message:

```
login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-gigya-placeholder='Email']")
```

Full Error Log:

> NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23192/47655697.py in 
> ----> 1 login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-gigya-placeholder='Email']")
>
> ~\miniconda3\envs\selenium_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
> in find_element(self, by, value)
> 974                 by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
> 975                 value = '[name="%s"]' % value
> --> 976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
> 977             'using': by,
> 978             'value': value})['value']
>
> ~\miniconda3\envs\selenium_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
> in execute(self, driver_command, params)
> 319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
> 320         if response:
> --> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> 322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
> 323                 response.get('value', None))
>
> ~\miniconda3\envs\selenium_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py
> in check_response(self, response)
> 240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
> 241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
> --> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> 243
> 244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):
>
> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"[data-gigya-placeholder='Email']"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this element is inside the iframe, so you have to switch to that iframe in order to access that element.
Also you are missing a wait / delay.
You should wait for the element to be ready before accessing it.
The best way to do that is to use explicit waits of expected conditions.
Try the following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://myibd.investors.com/secure/signin.aspx?eurl=https://marketsmith.investors.com/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#signin-iframe")))

login = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-gigya-placeholder='Email']")))
```

Comment: that gave me: "TimeoutException: Message:"
I completed a similar task in a Udemy course without using any `wait`

Comment: Well, this element is also inside an iframe. See the updated answer